# NFS mount fails on boot although IP Address is configured

Tags: boot, raspberry-pi, nfs

I am trying to mount my NFS shares at boot time on a Raspberry Pi 4.
It does not work and systemd complains that the network is unreachable.
Manually mounting each shares works as expected.
I have tried different things now. Instead of using `/etc/fstab` I use systemd services to mount the volumes like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Mount NFS share Music
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Mount]
What=10.5.0.34:/music
Where=home/pi/media_storage/music
Options=auto
Type=nfs
TimeoutSec=60

[Install]
WantedBy=remote-fs.target
```

The two services `systemd-networkd.service` and `systemd-networkd-wait-online.service` are enabled. Here is the `journalctl` output:

```
Nov 30 16:30:46 NextcloudPi dhcpcd[383]: eth0: IAID 32:23:48:46
Nov 30 16:30:46 NextcloudPi dhcpcd[383]: eth0: adding address fe80::9819:5d1a:3c86:8b41
Nov 30 16:30:46 NextcloudPi dhcpcd[383]: eth0: rebinding lease of 10.5.0.43
Nov 30 16:30:46 NextcloudPi dhcpcd[383]: eth0: probing address 10.5.0.43/24
Nov 30 16:30:46 NextcloudPi dhcpcd[383]: eth0: soliciting an IPv6 router
Nov 30 16:30:47 NextcloudPi systemd-networkd[152]: eth0: Gained IPv6LL
Nov 30 16:30:47 NextcloudPi systemd-timesyncd[281]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
Nov 30 16:30:47 NextcloudPi systemd-networkd-wait-online[183]: ignoring: lo
Nov 30 16:30:47 NextcloudPi systemd[1]: Started Wait for Network to be Configured.
Nov 30 16:30:47 NextcloudPi systemd[1]: Reached target Network is Online.
Nov 30 16:30:48 NextcloudPi systemd[1]: Mounting Mount NFS share Music...
Nov 30 16:30:48 NextcloudPi systemd[1]: Started /etc/rc.local Compatibility.
Nov 30 16:30:48 NextcloudPi mount[498]: mount.nfs: Network is unreachable
Nov 30 16:30:48 NextcloudPi systemd[1]: mnt-music.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited, status=32/n/a
Nov 30 16:30:48 NextcloudPi systemd[1]: mnt-music.mount: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 30 16:30:48 NextcloudPi systemd[1]: Failed to mount Mount NFS share Music.
Nov 30 16:30:48 NextcloudPi systemd[1]: Reached target Remote File Systems.
```

According to `journalctl` the interface is configured and has a valid IP address.
Why is `mount.nfs` complaining anyway?

Comment: Try adding "_netdev" the the options line. "Options=_netdev,auto"

Comment: did not help...

Comment: For your manual mount, did you run mount or "systemctl restart mount.nfs" ?

Comment: `systemctl start mnt-music.service`

Comment: Well, DHCP is not ready with its configuration. I need to use a different target than `network-online.target`. Right now, I have a messy workaround and use `sshd.service` as target, which works so far. Any suggestion and/or insight in how to use the `network-online.target` correctly would be appreciated. The [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/) is pretty useless.

Comment: Well, after installing apache and mysql the workaround does not work anymore. Myyy, was it easy to deal with rc.local...... miss it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you add the mount to the /etc/fstab file with the _netdev option does that also fail for you? Since systemd manages the mounts in fstab also.

Comment: didn't try that and since I have it running now I won't touch it anymore. I am really sick of systemd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `network-online.target` seems broken, no matter what I do, I developed a different and reliable solution.

I created a oneshot systemd script: "ping_barrier". It pings the NFS server until it succeeds. The `WantedBy=nfs-client.target` makes NFS wait for this service to finish.

```
[Unit]    
Description=Ping until Success

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/opt/ping_barrier.sh
StandardOutput=journal

[Install]
WantedBy=nfs-client.target
```

Here is the ping script, which loops, until the ping command is successful:

```
#!/bin/bash    
printf "%s" "waiting for FileServer ..."
while ! ping -c 1 -n -w 1 10.5.0.34 &> /dev/null
do
    printf "%c" "."
done
printf "\n%s\n"  "Server is back online"
```

Comment: After almost 2 years, this is the only one that worked! There must be a bug around `network-online.target`